# Filter data by day, 1 and 2 days before a date in another column - MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a data in two columns. I would like to filter it. First column - called `Filter me` should look up to the right cell next to it and if the date in the `Filter me` is the same or 2 days before the cell on the right it would be filtered.

```
Filter me           by this and 2 days before
16/05/2018 06:39    16/05/2018
15/05/2018 08:46    16/05/2018
14/05/2018 08:18    16/05/2018
13/05/2018 11:03    16/05/2018
11/05/2018 16:36    16/05/2018
09/05/2018 13:31    16/05/2018
17/05/2018 13:31    18/05/2018
13/05/2018 13:31    19/05/2018
```

Expected result:

```
Filter me           by this and 2 days before
16/05/2018 06:39    16/05/2018
15/05/2018 08:46    16/05/2018
14/05/2018 08:18    16/05/2018
17/05/2018 13:31    18/05/2018
```

How to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried so far? What research have you done? :)

Comment: I went to filtering menu and it gives an option to filter by date. Problem is - on the right column there are multiple dates, so I would have to choose one  filter, go back, choose another, filter, go back...

Comment: Did you try Advance Filter, I can show you how to execute it with help of helper column.